# Disable comments and pingbacks on old custom post types

Tags: comments, pingbacks

This SQL code will disable pingbacks on old posts and pages:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post';
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page';
```

I am looking to disable comments and pingbacks on all of my old custom post types.

Also by default I noticed Wordpress allows comments on new pages. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your question is "How can I run this SQL only for old post types?" What is the definition of an "old post type"?

Comment: An old custom post type is any "custom post type" post that has already been published. I need to run SQL code to disable comments and pingbacks everywhere..

Comment: Well, post types don't get published. Posts in a post type get published. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes this is what i meant s_ha_dum..

Comment: Let's make it easier. I want to disable comments and pingbacks everywhere in all single posts, custom post types and pages both new and old... I found out how to do this for new posts via the Wordpress options already.

Comment: Seems for old posts i need an SQL statement like the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's make it easier. I want to disable comments and pingbacks
>   everywhere in all single posts, custom post types and pages both new
>   and old.

You could [remove comment support for your post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support#Parameters).

```
remove_post_type_support( 'posttype', 'comments' );
// for each of  your post types of course
```

The same can be done [when registering the post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), for types that you create yourself. See the `supports` argument array. Simpley don't include `comments` in the list.

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum, in my register_post_type for cpt I have this line for supports: `array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', 'author', 'thumbnail' )` but comments do pop up somehow,, maybe 'cause it's of type 'post' or have general settings to enable comments..? anyways your `remove_post_type_support` fn line removes tham, thanks!